# Xamarin forms Android OAuth2 redirect no working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0

So, I've been working on this a couple days and I'm missing something.  I'm trying to create a `Xamarin` forms app that connects to a cloud accounting package using `OAuth2` authentication.  I've been working through the examples from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth). But I just can't get the redirect working.  Most likely something simple, but I'm not seeing or understanding

I'm created my authenticator as per the example, setting the redirect `url` to https://com.myproject.myapp/oauth2redirect.

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            <ClientId>,
            null,
            "openid profile email accounting.transactions accounting.settings offline_access",
            new <AuthoriseationEndpoint>,
            new Uri("https://com.myproject.myapp/oauth2redirect"),
            new <TokenEndpoint>,
            null,
            true);
```

Then, I'm created a new `activity` in my Android project with the `intentFilter`

```
    [Activity(Label = "CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity", NoHistory = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "com.myproject.myapp" },
        DataPath = "/oauth2redirect")]
    public class CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            var uri = new Uri(Intent.Data.ToString());

            // Load redirectUrl page
            AuthenticationState.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(uri);

            Finish();

            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

When I run my app, the login screen pops up as expected.  My app is registered okay with the cloud application fine but the redirect doesn't work.  I just get a browser error saying the site can't be reached. [Server](http://com.myproject.myapp) IP address could not be found `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
        <ClientId>,
        null,
        "openid profile email accounting.transactions accounting.settings offline_access",
        new <AuthoriseationEndpoint>,
        new Uri("https://com.myproject.myapp/oauth2redirect"),
        new <TokenEndpoint>,
        null,
        true);
```

to

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
        <ClientId>,
        null,
        "openid profile email accounting.transactions accounting.settings offline_access",
        new <AuthoriseationEndpoint>,
        new Uri("com.myproject.myapp:/oauth2redirect"),
        new <TokenEndpoint>,
        null,
        true);
```

You could not add `https://` to your custom redirect url after you define a Schemes. Note that only a single `/` can appear after the scheme component.
you could refer to [Redirect URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth#processing-the-redirect-url)

Comment: Thanks, did try that as I had read about the single /.  However, I get an error from the oAuth server as sson as presenter.login line if the https:// is not there.  I'm assuming it's because the redirect url in the cloud services don't match, but that won't let me use a uri without https

Comment: @Hursey Do you mean you have defined the redirect url `https://com.myproject.myapp/oauth2redirect`  on the OAuth service website  ?

Comment: Zhu Exactly.  They require a full Url for the call back.

Comment: @Hursey I don't quite understand what you mean. Maybe you can take a look at this [Xamarin.Auth](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/)

Comment: Ta for the interest.  Seems though that I'm not alone with this problem.  Have been talking it through with a couple other developers.  Apprently for now anyway, the OAuth2 process cloud accounting package doesn't support this type of application.

Comment: @Hursey That would be very sad，you can mention it on OAuth2's github

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT The question is more about to claimed https URL. But you answered for custom URI scheme.